# Anchor link in my menu doesn't work when clicking from another page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, hyperlink, menu

I am using the VamTam theme on WordPress for my church's website and have encountered an issue with trying to use anchor links in my site's Menu.

I set the link to the menu item "180 Staff" as "https://180church.com/about-180/#180-staff", as it is an anchor link within the "About 180" page. When I am already on the "About 180" page and I click the link, it works perfectly. However, when I try to click this menu item from any other page, it simply takes me to the top of the "About 180" page instead of the anchor point. You can see for yourself that when you click my link, it takes you to the top of the page. I have been researching users with similar issues and all of them said that opening their links in a new tab made it work for them--this is NOT the case for me. I set the IDs using `<h4 id="180-staff"></h4>`, but trying to use `<a name='180-staff'></a>` made no difference.

I am using Google Chrome, currently up to date on my Windows 10 PC and my Samsung phone and the issue occurs in both places. Somehow the issue is not present on my iPad running up to date Safari.

My working theory is that I have some script in place that is forcing the page to open at the top of the page, but I have no idea how to diagnose or resolve that. I am a bit of an amateur when it comes to fixing stuff "under the hood" so to speak.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more code I can add for clarity, I used ```<h4 id="180-staff"></h4>``` to add the anchors, and put the url https://180church.com/about-180/#180-staff in the website menu to link here. if there's any code under the hood that's getting in the way, it is unknown to me.